# Kubernetes Ingress deploy Angular assets (image) doesn't show

Tags: angular, kubernetes

I use Docker to package the Angular project (container use Nginx). When running on Docker, the images shows up ok, but when deploying to Kubernetes, using Ingress, all images in the `assets` folder do not appear.

Content-Type running on Docker. It's OK:

[Link Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qPUh.png)

But when running on Kubernetes. Content type always is text/html:

[Link Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MitKR.png)

Config Ingress Kubernetes. Service name `ssite`.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: abc-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "swing-static-ip"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "abc,xyz"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: sservice
          servicePort: 8000
  - host: xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path : /
        backend:
          serviceName: ssite
          servicePort: 80
      - path : /*
        backend:
          serviceName: ssite
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Did you try removing first path? It seems to be redundant. Also please try to delete and create ingress from scratch because GCP does not like modifications to existing ingress object.

Comment: At first I tried with no first path. It is the same as sservice part.

Comment: Try using the only path "/*".

Comment: I tried. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

In your nginx config set [default_type](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type) directive

> Defines the default MIME type of a response. Mapping of file name
>   extensions to MIME types can be set with the types directive.

```
server {
   ...
   default_type text/html;

   location /assets/imgs {
      default_type image/png;
   }

   location /assets/imgs {
      default_type image/jpeg;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding anotation :

are you using nginx ingress ?

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Comment: I tried using anotation rewrite-target. But the images still do not show.

Comment: i think it is issue if header passing n nginx ingress.